# ¿Cómo hacer un selector de bases de datos en PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion web que consiste en hacer unos calculos aritmeticos de los datos de una Base de Datos en mysql y mostrarlos con barras de progreso mediante progress bars. Actualmente el proyecto tiene 5 archivos:

- Login (contiene el query de conexion a mi cuenta de phpmyadmin)
- Operaciones (Selecciona los datos de la bbdd, hace las operaciones y guarda los resultados en variables de php)
- Index, variable1, variable2, variable3 (Son los 4 archivos que muestran las variables resultantes mediante barras de progreso).

Ahora quiero añadir un archivo mas que sea el selector de bases de datos. La idea seria que muestre la lista de bases de datos que hay en la cuenta de phpmyadmin en botones y que cuando el usuario haga clic en un boton pasen dos cosas:

- Que guarde el nombre de la bbdd del boton que ha hecho click para enviarselo al archivo del login y se conecte a la bbdd seleccionada. Para que el archivo de operaciones pueda hacer su trabajo en ESA bbdd y luego,
- Que envie al usuario a la pagina de index.php donde podra ver las variables resultantes para esa Base de Datos.

Aclaración: Las bases de datos son respuestas a un cuestionario, estos tienen la mismaa estructura y nombres de sus tablas y variables. Asi que lo unico que deberia pasar es que muestre resultados distintos segun el selector

He podido hacer la primera parte, tengo los botones y muestran el nombre de la bbdd, se puede hacer clic y te envia a la pagina de index, habiendo guardado el nombre y haciendo la conexion a la bbdd correctamente. Lo que pasa es que cuando cambio a una de las otros archivos, la variable se pierde y no se puede volver a conectar.

(Si se necesitan mas capturas del codigo puedo adjuntar)

Selector.php

```
<?php
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','');
    /* check connection */
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $show_db = mysqli_query($con,"SHOW DATABASES"); 
    echo "<div class='grid-container selector'>
    <form id='select' method='post' action='index.php'>";
    $i=1;
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show_db)) {
         echo "<input type='submit' name='button'
         class='grid-item btn button selector-item' value=".$row[0].">";
        $i++;

        $array[] = $row[0];
        }

    echo "</div>";

    for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++){
      if (isset($_POST['button'.$j.'']))
      {
        $db = $array[$j];
      }
  }     
?>
```

Login.php

```
<?php
$db = $_POST['button'];
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', $db);
/* check connection */
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código con el que realizas la conexión para poder decirte lo que necesitas modificar.

Comment: Gracias, ahora ya esta puesto

Comment: Al principio de cada archivo donde vas a trabajar con sesiones debes poner `session_start()`, sin eso las variables de sesión no funcionarán. No sé exactamente lo que quieres hacer, pero esto sería más simple si usaras Ajax. Así cargas en una página la lista de bases de datos (en un `select option` por ejemplo) y al seleccionar una de ellas mandas una petición Ajax para que se conecte a la base de datos elegida y haga lo que haya que hacer.

Comment: Si le pongo el session start en cada pagina las variables $_SESSION estaran disponibles desde cualquier archivo?? Lo que me pasaba es que si lo guardaba y luego en el index ponia el include del selector, tambien me cargaba todo el html

Comment: He añadido session_start() a las demas paginas pero como tienen includes entre ellas me dice que la session ya se ha iniciado

Comment: Sí, las variables de sesión tienen la función de hacer persistir información entre varios archivos. Lo del include no entiendo qué quieres decir. Yo lo que creo es que no te aclaras con lo que quieres hacer y te estás haciendo tremendo lío. En la pregunta tampoco es claro ni el contexto ni lo que quieres. Sugiero que trates de explicarlo en limpio de la forma más sencilla posible: *quiero esto y lo otro, y para lograrlo he creado este archivo que tiene esto y cuando se le da aquí debe abrirse este otro archivo que hace lo otro*.

Comment: Edito mi comentario inicial

Comment: A ver si ahora me he explicado mejor